# How to show a user what new features they can use on a b2b website

Tags: website-design, web-app, best-practice, b2b

I hope this question is in this sites scope

In our company we have a b2b website, which is not the most beautiful around. It's very "oldschool" and it's not responsive or adaptive (which is quite unusual these days). A redesign has to be done later this year, but we can't really say when because our resources are limited.

We have many features on our website which are really good and which our competitors in our market don't offer.

The problem is, that our customers don't know that these features exist. They are also not looking for it, because our website is basically just an online-catalog/shop and when the user lands on our website, the only thing he wants to do is get articles in his shopping cart and order them.

Most of our customers are carpenters and electricians from small companies but we also have customers from bigger dealer-companies.

Now we're thinking about how to promote our features. For our new self-developed chat feature, we're using an arrow which appears whenever a user logs in, once a month. like this (it says: if you have questions, chat with us!):

[image]

but now we want to promote even more of our features which are quite hidden. like these two features which i circled with red colour:

[image]

As you can see, these features are quite hidden.

My question would be: what would be the best way to get the users attentions for our features. should we make more arrows which show the user what we've got? I'm just afraid that we have like 15 arrows jumping up and down our website in the end.

If you need more information about our website, i'm more than happy to provide more details.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing more about what those features do, I think your best bet is to suggest those features when it's relevant in the user's journey.

It looks like one of your features is a new format/file type for exporting the contents of the table.

Instead of making it an icon next to another icon, bundle all of the export features up into one screen, and let the person open that screen by tapping a link or button which says "Export".

Then, where they're selecting how they want the export, your new option is added to a list of the original options. You've given them all the same visibility, and the person is likely to check all of the options to see what's available before they make a choice.